# How do I write a setup.py and other installation files in Python that set path?

Tags: python, path, installation

I have several packages in folder Top. The path is set at the command prompt such that each package contains some python files that use other packages' modules.

I have the following files in Top directory: setup.py, MANIFEST, MANIFEST.in, README. I wish to modify the setup files such that the path is set during installation. Does PYTHONPATH set it, and does it need to go into a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate actions here are

- Packages do not mess with PYTHONPATH. Never.
- [Instead, you write an setup.py entry point to your command line scripts](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)
- When the user installs the package using `pip install` the command line script is automatically added to user's PATH, which is hopefully inside virtualenv
- This command line script is generated during the install, so that it points to the PYTHONPATH of virtualenv or system-wide Python installation. The path is hardcoded at the script head, pointing to the current Python interpreter.

More info

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/